# JSF: mixing GET & POST parameters

Tags: java, jsf

I'm trying to send a POST request from a page which already contains a GET parameter. There is no error thrown but the control flow seems to jump over the invoke application phase. If I'm trying the same POST request from a page with no GET parameters all things work perfectly.

**The Template Implementation** This on implements the required component depending on the GET parameter named *action*

```
<ui:define name = "front">

    <cd:accountSettings rendered = "${accountController.action == 'details'}"/>

    <cd:accountTabShortcut rendered = "${accountController.action == 'loginfo'}"/>  

</ui:define>
```

**The component**

```
<cc:implementation>

    <h:form id = "auth-fm">

        <div class = "fm-input">
            <h:outputLabel for="firstName">#{appMessage['form.label.name.first']}</h:outputLabel>
            <div class = "fm-input-elem">
                <h:inputText styleClass="input-auth" id="firstName" label="firstName" value="#{accountController.firstName}">
                    <f:validator validatorId="nameValidator" />
                    <f:ajax event = "blur" render = "firstNameMessage" />
                </h:inputText>
                <div class = "fm-err">
                    <h:message id = "firstNameMessage" for = "firstName" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "fm-input">
            <h:outputLabel for="lastName">#{appMessage['form.label.name.last']}</h:outputLabel>
            <div class = "fm-input-elem">
                <h:inputText styleClass="input-auth" id="lastName" label="lastName" value="#{accountController.lastName}">
                    <f:validator validatorId="nameValidator" />
                    <f:ajax event = "blur" render = "lastNameMessage" />
                </h:inputText>
                <div class = "fm-err">
                    <h:message id = "lastNameMessage" for = "lastName" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "fm-submit">
            <h:commandButton styleClass="bn-auth lk-bn-rng" id = "authButton" value="#{appMessage['form.text.register']}" action="#{accountController.changeDetails}" />
        </div>

    </h:form>
```

**The Managed Bean**

```
public class AccountController extends BaseController{

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("=> Account Controller - init() - enter");

        action = getParam("action");

        firstName = sessionController.getAuthUser().getFirstName();
                lastName = sessionController.getAuthUser().getLastName();

        System.out.println("=< Account Controller - init() - exit");
    }

     public String changeDetails(){
        System.out.println("=> Account Controller - Change Details - start");
        System.out.println("First Name: " + firstName);
        System.out.println("Last Name: " + lastName);
        System.out.println("=< Account Controller - Change Details - start");
        return "account";
    }
    }
```

When I'm following the phase listeners the changeDetails() method is never called.
The post call is made from a page like : *mySite.com/account.xhtml?action=details*. I think that this may be the problem but I can;t know for sure and I don't know any workaround besides split the content in two pages: accountDetails and accountLoginfo.

**LE:**
I'm using JSF 2.0 with Glassfish3 container and XHTML facelets for the GUI.

Comment: Needs more info... what app server? what jsf implementation?  are you using VDL or JSP for your view rendering?

Comment: @JohnAment  
I updated the question

Comment: So you want it to call the method without hitting the command button?  I think you need to add a view param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the bean in the view scope. This way the `@PostConstruct` will run only once on initial request on the view and the bean will live as long as you're interacting with the same view by ajax and by returning `null` or `void` on action methods.

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF2 - Managed bean scopes](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes)